# Pancard structure validation in contact form 7?

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I want to do pancard validation in contact form 7.

Its limited to india only.

the structure of pancard in India is as follows.. for example : AAAAA9999A

First five characters are letters (A-Z),
next 4 numerics (0-9),
last character letter (A-Z)
please help i am beginner in wordpress

Answer (score 0):

You can validate like

```
if (!preg_match("/^([a-zA-Z]){5}([0-9]){4}([a-zA-Z]){1}?$/", $pannumber)) {
  //Invalid Pan Card Details
}
```